# Infinite loop with v-for inside a v-for

Tags: vue.js, infinite-loop

Can someone help me find out how I can achieve a loop inside a loop to print out a report of people and peoples annual leave.

Basically I have this:

```
<div v-for="user_list in user_list_filtered()">
  <div class="user_heading"><h2>{{ user_list.first_name }}</h2></div>
  <div class="report_content" v-for="user_leave in user_leave_filtered(user_list['.key'])">
    <div class="first_date_content">
        {{ user_leave.start_time | formatDate }}
    </div>
    <div class="days_taken_content">
        {{ checkLSL(user_leave.hours, user_leave.type, false) }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="leave_content">
    <div class="total_leave_title">
        Total Leave Taken
    </div>
    <div class="total_hours">
        {{ getTotalLeave() }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So this iterates through a Firebase DB and gets all of the users, it then loops through each user one by one and using the [.key] finds that users leave and loops through all of the leave as it outputs. Then onto the next user and there leave.

While this works it will continue to loop infinitely and says in my console.

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

Can someone explain maybe a better way to do this without the infinite loop or a solution to avoid it constantly looping?

Thanks

EDIT

Filter functions

```
user_leave_filtered(userPassed) {
var self = this
return this.userLeave.filter(function(i) {
    if (i.users_id === userPassed &&
        ((i.start_time >= self.getUnix(self.firstDate) && i.start_time <= self.getUnix(self.lastDate)) ||
        (self.firstDate === null || self.firstDate === '' || self.lastDate === null || self.lastDate === ''))) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
})
},
user_list_filtered() {
var self = this

return this.userList.filter(function(i) {

    var passed = false

    if (self.userToShow === i['.key'] || self.userToShow === 'All') {
        // Track whether to filter out this leave or not
        self.userLeave.forEach(function(element) {
            if (element.users_id === i['.key']) {
                passed = true
            }
        })
    }

    return passed
})
},
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like there might be a cycle in your data. It would help to see the actual data. Can you update the question with a sample of the data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi SamohVII, if possible can you please add  a sample data here (edit question). Because your code looks fine, may be you just need a tweak to make it work, according to  the data you are having.

Comment: Make sure that `use_list_filtered` and `user_leave_filtered` are not updating data repeatedly, otherwise you'll have the infinite loop problem. Instead, make sure that the results are appropriately cached or pre-loaded. Maybe even consider using a `computed` property if feasible.

Comment: I added some more info if that helps in debugging this. Sorry if it sucks. I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle - would be much easier to help you.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to create a fiddle, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was a function (checkLSL()) I was using to calculate some totals through the loops. I have some info on how to fix and seems to be working fine.
Thanks